# C++ Determine type of void* from two classes

Tags: c++, types, casting

I'm using wxWidgets and I have a search-function in my map-editor for my online game.

I search objects for different criteria and put these objects in the ComboBox list by their name and also add the object as reference data (`void*`),

I have an event `onClickResult` I want to mark and jump to the object which works but it crashes my application when switching between object types as it seems I cannot "`reinterpret_cast`" to determine the class objects which have no relation (no subclasses, two independent classes without any relation).

Question: Is there any way to determine what data-type is located in a `void*` (`event.GetClientData()` is returning `void*`) and cast it properly?

```
void SearchResultWindow::OnClickResult(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    Item* item = reinterpret_cast<Item*>(event.GetClientData());
    if (item) {
        this->selectRelatedMapItem(item);
    } else {
        Creature* creature = reinterpret_cast<Creature*>(event.GetClientData());
        if (creature) {
            this->selectRelatedMapCreature(creature);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `std::variant` might be what you are looking instead of `void*`.

Answer (score 5):

No there is no portable way of doing this in C++.

Once you cast to `void*` or `const void*` you are telling the compiler that you are going to keep track of the type yourself.

One solution here would be to have a base class from which all your objects inherit, and cast the `void*` to that type. From there, regular polymorphism can take over.

Comment: Okay maybe I can introduce a base class for this two classes. Thanks for the hint I try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the object itself as the `void*` client data, but rather a pointer to a struct having sufficient members to lookup the object. For example some identifier to the container holding the object and an index into the container.

Comment: Thats another good approach but requires alot of refactoring. I think I can go well with Bathsheba's solution but I will keep it in mind for further projects.